# How to sort json objects using the order of another json

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular, ionic3

I have a list of parks *(park_list)* that can be sorted by distance and by area.

I already succeeded in sorting by distance using the code below:

```
sortList(index){
  return function(a, b){
    return (a[index] === b[index] ? 0 : (a[index] < b[index] ? -1 : 1));
  }
}
```

However, the problem with sorting by area is different from sorting by distance. I need to sort the area depending on the order of a given area list *(area_list)*.

My *park_list* is something like this:

```
[
    {
        "parkName" : "park4",
        "area_id" : "4"
    },
    {
        "parkName" : "park2",
        "area_id" : "2"
    },
    {
        "parkName" : "park1",
        "area_id" : "1"
    },
    {
        "parkName" : "park3",
        "area_id" : "3"
    },

]
```

My *area_list* goes like this:

```
{
    "cityId": "1",
    "areaId": "1",
    "areaName": "area1"
}, {
    "cityId": "1",
    "areaId": "2",
    "areaName": "area2"
}, {
    "cityId": "1",
    "areaId": "3",
    "areaName": "area3"
}, {
    "cityId": "1",
    "areaId": "4",
    "areaName": "area4"
}
```

I need to sort my *park_list* depending on the order of the **areaId** in *area_list*.

So if my *area_list* goes something like this:

```
{
    "cityId": "1",
    "areaId": "2",
    "areaName": "area2"
}, {
    "cityId": "1",
    "areaId": "4",
    "areaName": "area4"
}, {
    "cityId": "1",
    "areaId": "1",
    "areaName": "area1"
}, {
    "cityId": "1",
    "areaId": "3",
    "areaName": "area1"
}
```

My *park_list* should be sorted like this:

```
[
    {
        "parkName" : "park2",
        "area_id" : "2"
    },
    {
        "parkName" : "park4",
        "area_id" : "4"
    },
    {
        "parkName" : "park1",
        "area_id" : "1"
    },
    {
        "parkName" : "park3",
        "area_id" : "3"
    },

]
```

I am really having a hard time about this. I would really appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: what kind of solution are you after (you added angular and ionic3 as tags)?. also, do you have any control on the list structures or the format is a given?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an object which keeps the index of each `area_id` by using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method and later use the object for sorting.

```
const area_list_index = area_list.reduce((obj, { areaId }, i) => {
  obj[areaId] = i;
  return obj;
}, {})


park_list.sort((a, b) => area_list_index[a.area_id] - area_list_index[b.area_id])
```

```js
let park_list = [{
    "parkName": "park4",
    "area_id": "4"
  },
  {
    "parkName": "park2",
    "area_id": "2"
  },
  {
    "parkName": "park1",
    "area_id": "1"
  },
  {
    "parkName": "park3",
    "area_id": "3"
  },

]

let area_list = [{
  "cityId": "1",
  "areaId": "2",
  "areaName": "area2"
}, {
  "cityId": "1",
  "areaId": "4",
  "areaName": "area4"
}, {
  "cityId": "1",
  "areaId": "1",
  "areaName": "area1"
}, {
  "cityId": "1",
  "areaId": "3",
  "areaName": "area1"
}]

const area_list_index = area_list.reduce((obj, {
  areaId
}, i) => {
  obj[areaId] = i;
  return obj;
}, {})


park_list.sort((a, b) => area_list_index[a.area_id] - area_list_index[b.area_id])

console.log(park_list);
```

Alternately you can use [`Array#findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) method to get index but it won't be efficient.

```
park_list.sort((a, b) => area_list.findIndex((o) => o.areaId == a.area_id) - area_list.findIndex((o) => o.areaId == b.area_id))
```

```js
let park_list = [{
    "parkName": "park4",
    "area_id": "4"
  },
  {
    "parkName": "park2",
    "area_id": "2"
  },
  {
    "parkName": "park1",
    "area_id": "1"
  },
  {
    "parkName": "park3",
    "area_id": "3"
  },

]

let area_list = [{
  "cityId": "1",
  "areaId": "2",
  "areaName": "area2"
}, {
  "cityId": "1",
  "areaId": "4",
  "areaName": "area4"
}, {
  "cityId": "1",
  "areaId": "1",
  "areaName": "area1"
}, {
  "cityId": "1",
  "areaId": "3",
  "areaName": "area1"
}]



park_list.sort((a, b) => area_list.findIndex((o) => o.areaId == a.area_id) - area_list.findIndex((o) => o.areaId == b.area_id))

console.log(park_list);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) for the wanted order and sort by the index of the same key.

```js
var park_list = [{ parkName: "park4", area_id: "4" }, { parkName: "park2", area_id: "2" }, { parkName: "park1", area_id: "1" }, { parkName: "park3", area_id: "3" }],
    area_list = [{ cityId: "1", areaId: "2", areaName: "area2" }, { cityId: "1", areaId: "4", areaName: "area4" }, { cityId: "1", areaId: "1", areaName: "area1" }, { cityId: "1", areaId: "3", areaName: "area1" }],
    order = new Map(area_list.map(({ areaId }, i) => [areaId, i]));
    
park_list.sort(({ area_id: a }, { area_id: b }) => order.get(a) - order.get(b));

console.log(park_list);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```